# How to convert a JSONObject to a JSONArray

Tags: java, android, json

Could you help me to parse this JSON string?

```
[{"Id":"b8d2cd88-b042-46df-b82f-1ec29cc24760","Name":"Stedelijk Gymnasium Arnhem","Url":"https://sga.magister.net"}]
```

I retrieved this string from a server and converted it to a JSONObject, but I can't access the Id, name, and URL, so I want to convert it to a JSONArray. I have already tried using JSONSerializer and JSONParser (because I found those in answers on other posts), but somehow I can't import those classes. Could you please help me?

Comment: Are you using Json.org or Gson or other library for parsing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I retrieved this string from a server and converted it to a JSONObject

Returned string is `JSONArray` instead of `JSONObject`,so convert it to `JSONArray` then get `JSONObject` from it.

```
JSONArray jsonArr=new JSONArray("SERVER_STRING");
JSONObject jsonObj=jsonArr.getJSONObject(0);
// get all values from jsonobject using keys
 String strId=jsonObj.getString("Id");
 ....
```